# Call C# method from Razor View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to ASP.net I am trying to use MVC. I have a method that gets the current users information from a sql database using Linq. How would I get those result into the view and use them anywhere in the site?

My method to get user information:

```
public List<AspNetUser> GetCurrentUser()
{
    FulfillmentContext db = new FulfillmentContext();
    string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserName();

    var currentUser = (from u in db.AspNetUsers
                    join ur in db.AspNetUserRoles on u.Id equals ur.UserId
                    join r in db.AspNetRoles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                    where u.UserName == username
                    select u).ToList();

    return currentUser;
}
```

Comment: This code brings up some questions... Why do you expect multiple users to have the same username? Won't that cause a variety of problems in user management? And how can multiple users be *the current user* simultaneouslty? Aside from that, doesn't the `User` that's part of the framework (both in the Controller and in a View) contain the information you're looking for? Aside from that, *in general* if you want to pass data to a view you would do so by including that data on the model sent to the view. Though there are a variety of approaches for a modern web application to show data on a page.

Comment: @SGekko you can create partial view and use it any where.

Comment: I don't expect multiple users to have the same username. This query is pulling only the current logged in user's username.

Comment: @SGekko: The method is returning a `List<AspNetUser>`.  If you only ever expect there to be one then why return a list?

Comment: Good point. Being new to this that is a mistake on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should load it up in your model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    FulfillmentContext db = new FulfillmentContext();
    string username = 
    HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserName();

    var currentUser = (from u in db.AspNetUsers
                    join ur in db.AspNetUserRoles on u.Id equals ur.UserId
                    join r in db.AspNetRoles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                    where u.UserName == username
                    select u).First();

    var model = new Model();
    model.CurrentUser = currentUser;

    return View(model);    
}
```

However, you can create a HTML helper extension:

```
public static AspNetUser GetCurrentUser(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    FulfillmentContext db = new FulfillmentContext();
    string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserName();

    var currentUser = (from u in db.AspNetUsers
                    join ur in db.AspNetUserRoles on u.Id equals ur.UserId
                    join r in db.AspNetRoles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                    where u.UserName == username
                    select u).First();

    return currentUser;
}
```

Then call it from your view:

```
@{
    var user = Html.GetCurrentUser();
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the other option you offered, load it in my model? Maybe in a view model?